# Can I Select An Alias In Select Query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a query like this:

```
select (sum(blablabla)-sum(blablabla)) as total
```

Can I use total in a `select` query like this ?

```
select total from(
select (sum(blablabla)-sum(blablabla)) as total
) as tbl
```

Comment: Yes. `total` will be returned as an actual field from the sub-query.

Comment: you can do like "select tbl.total from(select (sum(blablabla)-sum(blablabla)) as total) as tbl;"

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can select an alias in select query.

For that please use following query:

```
SELECT t.total FROM ( SELECT (SUM(10+10)) AS total) t
```

Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
SELECT (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(t1.email) as emails_ids FROM t1) as emails_ids FROM t1
```

Comment: i used it as example column name replace it with your exact table column name